# Spring JDBCTemplate throwing BadSqlGrammarException

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have an SQL query that is executed using Spring JDBCTemplate to retrieve data from an Oracle DB. While executing the statement, `org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException` is thrown.

The same SQL statement returns proper results when run in the SQL Plus console.

Below is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT O.ORGID FROM ORGANISATIONS O WHERE O.ORGTYPE NOT IN ('P','G') AND O.USERID = 40";

ArrayList<Organisations> orgsList = new  ArrayList<Organisations>();
Object[] paramsArray = new Object[]{};

orgsList = (ArrayList<Organisations>) getJdbcTemplate().query(query.toString(), paramsArray ,
            new RowMapper<Organisations>(){
        public MetricsRoleMap mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            // Data retrieval code;
        };
    });
```

Here is the error generated:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [ SELECT DISTINCT O.ORGID FROM ORGANISATIONS O WHERE O.ORGTYPE NOT IN ('P','G') AND O.USERID = 40]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231) [spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) [spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660) [spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695) [spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727) [spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737) [spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787) [spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Similar code that I wrote for another method works well. I think there is a minor mistake here, but I am unable to find it.

Comment: can u paste your exception here?

Comment: Paste the error and the query you are creating, if you don't have parameters then what sense does it make to pass in an empty array.

Comment: I tried passing parameters using array as well. But same error occurred.

Comment: The error message says "invalid column name". So check that all the column names you're using actually exist.

Comment: The same query executes correctly in sql plus console.

Comment: I am getting same error